# My text overlaps my div

Tags: html, css, scss-lint

I need to wrap my text in a `div`. But if I use `flex-wrap`, it doesn't wrap the text and div's width becomes larger. I just want to make the wrapped text to be at the center.

```css
.flex-container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <span>longlonglonglonglonglonglong</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `word-break: break-all`:

```css
.flex-container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: red;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <span>longlonglonglonglonglonglong</span>
</div>
```